# I want to copy all the tags related to P20OBT in one shot. Please see the tag list below:

Tags: notepad++

I want to copy all the tags related to P20OBT in one shot. Please see the tag list below:

```
            9975/4.3/3          P0OBT   
            9975/4.3/3          P20OBT               
            9975/4.3/3          P25OBT              
            9975/4.3/3          P30OBT              
            9975/4.3/3          P30STT  
            9975/4.3/3          PEXOBT                
            9975/4.3/3          PEXSTT 
            9975/4.3/9          LOELPD 
            9975/4.5/3          PRESS/6.1/76     
            AIR/1049/1          PRESS/6.1/90     
            AIR/1075/1          PRESS/6.1/91     
            AIR/1087/1          P0OBT   
            AIR/1088/1          P0OBT   
            AIR/1089/1          P20OBT                
            AIR/1090/1          P20OBT
```

Easiest way would be appreciated.... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want in a direct way using a search to bookmark the lines, then copy bookmarked lines:

- Open the find Dialog, go to the Mark tab:

  - **Find What:** `^.*P20OBT.*$`
  - check **Bookmark line**
  - check **Regular Expression**
  - Click **Clear all marks**
  - Click **Mark All**
- Now the lines are bookmarked in your file, use the menu:
  Search -> Bookmark -> Copy bookmarked lines
  to put the lines containing P20OBT into the clipboard, so that you can paste them in another file

But I have to admit Totos solution requires less steps.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way is to delete all lines that don't contain `P20OBT`.

Here is a way to go:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^\s+\S+\s+(?!P20OBT)\S+\s*\R`
- Replace with: `NOTHING`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

This will keep only lines that contain `P20OBT`.

In your case:

```
        9975/4.3/3          P20OBT               
        AIR/1089/1          P20OBT                
        AIR/1090/1          P20OBT
```

Make sure you have checked `Regular expression`